# How does the Symfony Response Object set http headers?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I'm using Sliex framework. I had a problem with redirection when I use `\Silex\Application::redirect`method. I found that when I'm trying to redirect by http-headers, instead of symfony "send" the response seemed to call the `__toString` method.

This is my curl output:

```
bash-4.2$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8082/
* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 8082 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x1ea0970
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1ea0970) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8082 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.32.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8082
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 20 Sep 2014 08:02:52 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.15 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora) PHP/5.5.15
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.15
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=*****; path=/
< Content-Length: 116
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date:          Sat, 20 Sep 2014 08:02:52 GMT
Location:      /login

* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

I can't understand why but it echo http-headers.

**UPDATE**

My script is something like this:

```
<?php class Contorller {
    public action( \Silex\Application $app ){
       return $app->redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

Routing script:

```
<?php
$core = new \Silex\Application;
$core->get("/another/action", "\\Controller::action")
$core->match("/login","\\AnotherController::login")->method('POST|GET');
```

The login action has no logic, and it just renders a twig template.

Comment: How does your php script look like?

Comment: Can you add your routing instructions and login's controller?

Answer (score 5):

Calling $app->redirect() returns a new [RedirectResponse](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Application.php#L457) object with a default status of 302.

The following is taken directly from the [Symfony Response Object Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#response)

To set headers on the Symfony Response object use the `headers->set` method.

```
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class Controller {
    public function action( \Silex\Application $app ){

        $response = new RedirectResponse('/login', 302);

        // the headers public attribute is a ResponseHeaderBag
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Your code worked perfectly once the typos in the method names were corrected (Contorller changed to Controller).

```
class Controller {
    public function action( \Silex\Application $app ){
       return $app->redirect('/login', 302);
    }
}

class AnotherController {
    public function login( \Silex\Application $app ){
       return new Response($app['twig']->render('blank.html.twig'));
    }
}

$app->get("/another/action", "\Controller::action");
$app->match("/login","\AnotherController::login")->method('POST|GET');
```